# Regular exp[ression in XSLT

Tags: regex, xslt

Can somebody help me to understand this below regular expreesion in XSLT.

```
regexp:match(test-graph.api.example.com, '(?=CN).*\.(.*)(\.)(.*)(?&lt;=com)', 'i')
```

What would be the output and how to interpret this regular expression.

Please let me know

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/HpRcQH/1

Answer (score -1):

Is should be read this way:

```
(?=CN).*\.(.*)(\.)(.*)(?<=com)
```

explanation:

```
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
    * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing Group (.*)
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
    * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
2nd Capturing Group (\.)
\. matches the character . literally
3rd Capturing Group (.*)
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
    * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Positive Lookbehind (?<=com)
Assert that the Regex below matches
com matches the characters com literally
```

The `i` modifiers means that the regex is case **i**nsentive.